# How to move several files in current directory by name to another directory?

Tags: mv

I have several CSV files in my downloads folder that I'd like to move to another directory to work with. Let's call them (1) `test.csv`; (2) `bob.csv`; and (3) `foobar.csv`; . If these were the only files in the current directory I know I could move them using `mv *.csv /file/path/`.

However, in some cases there might be hundreds of other CSV files in the downloads folder and I'd just like to move the most recent ones (viewed using `ls -alt | head -10` for example).

Is there a way I can do something like

`mv ["test.csv", "bob.csv", "foobar.csv"] /file/path`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just remove the brackets and commas and you are done.

```
mv "test.csv" "bob.csv" "foobar.csv" /file/path
```